# Delphi, How to reset a multidimensional Array

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array

I have a global array like this one:

```
FExample = Class
private
     MyArray: Array of Array of Integer;
End;
```

I fill it in in the code:

```
SetLenght(MyArray,Lenght(MyArray)+1);//The extension of the array now is 1
MyArray[High(MyArray)][0] := 3;
MyArray[High(MyArray)][1] := 3;

SetLenght(MyArray,Lenght(MyArray)+1);//The extension of the array now is 1
MyArray[High(MyArray)][1] := 31;

 ......
 //The extension of the array now is maybe 14 or 28 or whatever and the second dimension also could be anyone.
 SetLenght(MyArray,Lenght(MyArray)+1);
 MyArray[High(MyArray)][0] := 2;
```

Now I want the array empty like it was before set the first value, before initialize. What do I have to do ?

Comment: You never allocate the inner arrays. So your code will fail with runtime errors (after you fix the spelling of length).

Answer (score 8):

You can set the length of a multi-dimensional array with one call to

```
SetLength(MyArray, dim1, dim2 [, more dimensions]);
```

To Reset the array call

```
SetLength(MyArray, 0); 
SetLength(MyArray, dim1, dim2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Some methods:

```
MyArray := Nil;

Finalize(MyArray);

SetLength(MyArray, 0);
```

P.S. Note that such extension of array one by one is not effective. Consider TList<> and other possibilities.

P.P.S. You didn't show real code